# How can I set the heatmap bucket boundry in grafana to milliseconds when using stackdriver

Tags: heatmap, grafana, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to set up a heatmap graph for request latencies in grafana, using a stackdriver backend.

With the following query I get the right heatmap, however the bucket labels are in seconds without decimals, which means there is an 8,4,2 and 1 second bucket, and then many 0 second buckets. Is there a way to switch to ms labels?

For clarification: the bucket names coming back in the result of the query are integers, so changing the units or decimal places in the visualisation won't help.

[Query as seen in grafana editor (for better readability)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyklc.png)

[Currently the graph looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcS8c.png)

```
"queries": [
        {
          "refId": "A",
          "intervalMs": 15000,
          "datasourceId": 14,
          "metricType": "serviceruntime.googleapis.com/api/request_latencies",
          "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
          "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_DELTA",
          "alignmentPeriod": "stackdriver-auto",
          "groupBys": [],
          "view": "FULL",
          "filters": [
            // -> some more removed for privacy reasons
            "AND",
            "resource.type",
            "=",
            "api"
          ],
          "aliasBy": "{{bucket}}",
          "type": "timeSeriesQuery"
        }
      ]
```